# 'Your answer' leads to tips for stackoverflow not english.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I select 'Your Answer' to a question, the guidance says:

> Thanks for contributing an answer to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange!
>   ...
>   To learn more, see our tips on *writing great answers*.

This leads to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer:

> ### Answer well-asked questions
>
> Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...
>
> > ```
> > ...are not about programming as defined in the help center.
> > ```

It should actually lead to https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer:

> ### Answer well-asked questions
>
> Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...
>
> > ```
> > ...are not about English language and usage as defined in the help center.
> > ```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently we had this link to the Stack Overflow how to answer page across the network.

This is fixed and should be available in the next deploy.

Thanks for reporting!